# MacPort : Is a given package a dependecy for another one ?

Tags: macports

My MacPort package are becoming the huge mess. I probably won't use some of them and I was wondering how I could know if a given package is a dependecy for another one.

For example I have GTK3 installed. How could I know which other installed package needs GTK3.

Answer (score 2):

From [Macports guide](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.common-tasks.html#using.common-tasks.finddepending) You can list all the ports dependent on a port x say

```
port echo depends:x
```

To find ports that have no dependants use

```
port echo leaves
```

Comment: You could even pipe the leaves into the depends:x to get all the ports who are leaves and are not depended on

Comment: @RossMcKinley leaves are ports that are not depend on so that will just goer the leaves

Comment: Oh right, my mistake. I didn't read those properly.

Comment: For your particular use case of finding the package that pulled in gtk3: `port installed rdependentof:gtk3 and requested`. This prints the ports you manually installed (`requested`) and are in the recursive tree of dependents, i.e. that somehow indirectly or directly depend on gtk3.